# Unable to format with prettier for my monaco code editor

Tags: reactjs, prettier, monaco-editor

I am making a code editor in react using monaco code editor
I am trying to use prettier to format my code in the code editor.
Its giving error ' TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'languages')
at standalone.mjs:22:694'

This is the code

```
import parser from "prettier/parser-babel";

try {
    const test = async () => {
      const code = `function add(a, b) {
              return a + b;
            }`;

      const prettier = await import("prettier/standalone");

      const formattedCode = await prettier.format(code, {
        semi: true,
        parser: "babel",
        plugins: [parser],
        useTabs: false,
        
      });
      console.log({ formattedCode });
    };
    test();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log({ e });
  }
```

I tried using different parser too but it did not work.

Comment: I am running into this now and can't figure out how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

Try using these imports:

```js
import babelPlugin from "prettier/plugins/babel";
import estreePlugin from "prettier/plugins/estree";
```

I also included an import for the `estree` plugin because you'll need it to parse JavaScript :-)

Answer (score 0):

On the offchance anyone else encounter this I had the wrong plugin import path and I also needed estree.  I am formatting SVG.

Before

```js
import babel from 'prettier/parser-babel'

const formatted = await format(code, {
      parser: 'babel',
      plugins: [babel],
})
```

After

```js
import babel from 'prettier/plugins/babel'
import esTree from 'prettier/plugins/estree'

const formatted = await format(code, {
      parser: 'babel',
      plugins: [babel, esTree],
})
```